# full page content snapshot with scroll in JPanel

Tags: java

I want full page snapshop of jpanel that have content larger than panel size so content is scrollable but I am unable to get snapshot of non visible area in JPanel. So far I have tried these codes

```
Container c = getContentPane();
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(c.getWidth(), c.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
c.paint(img.getGraphics());
```

```
WritableImage snapshot = view.snapshot(new SnapshotParameters(), null);
RenderedImage renderedImage = SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(snapshot, null);
```

and using `Robot` but none of them worked for me.

For clarification of what is happening:
https://pasteboard.co/I9kup9w.png

Comment: Although the title sounds different, this question seems to address the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551646/convert-a-jpanel-to-an-image-in-a-jscrollpane

Comment: not completely but this problem is same as mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433919/screenshot-of-the-full-web-page-loaded-into-javafx-webview-component-not-only-v